# TLC plate and Rf values

Tags: homework, experimental-chemistry

[image]

I have calculated the Rf values for 6 samples. How do I determine which is really Sriracha ?

Comment: I was tempted to vote close this as a homework question, but the problem posed is flawed and unanswerable as was given. That's worth pointing out to the OP.

Comment: I don't see how this is unanswerable. My interpretation of the diagram was that all spots were run at the spotting line, so the real compound is the one that moved up 2cm (the third one).

Answer (score 1):

> Tl;DR - You do not have enough information.

I cannot help but think that this question is not answerable. You have four samples: Huy Fong Sriracha and three "knock-offs". There are six lanes on the plate. All six samples contain potassium sorbate.

If the question was something more like: You have five mysterious hot sauces and one of them is Sriracha... Then the TLC plate makes sense. One of those poorly labeled lanes is sriracha and the others are the mystery sauces. You just need to pick the one that gives the same pattern of spots with the same Rf values.

You don't have that. You have a mismatch between number of lanes and number of samples. You don't know which one is the authentic standard. All of the sauces contain the potassium sorbate (and they should - its a common preservative). You've determined the Rf values and that is all you can do. Well, maybe not all. 
I can tell that lane 1 and lane 4 probably contain the same sauce and likewise lanes 2 and 5. Other than that, Jan's comment is correct. The potassium sorbate should always be at the same Rf (and since it is ionic, that likely means at the bottom of the TLC plate).

Comment: I’m not sure where you took the certainty that *all* samples contain potassium sorbate. If I looked at the TLC in an unbiased manner, I would say that exactly *one* contained sorbate.

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of odd so I'm just going to propose a solution. You really have to assume some quirky chemistry and a bit of logic puzzle analysis to "solve" this problem.

I think this is the sort of problem where if you really know chemistry that you're easily overcome with analysis paralysis. This problem has a number of chemical uncertainties which render the problem rather meaningless for a real chemistry problem. First the extract conditions are unspecified so it is very unclear what sort of species would be extracted from the sauce. Second the development solution is unspecified. Third the reagent used to develop the TLC plate is unspecified. Fourth sorbate is a preservative, not really a "key" flavor component, so making the analysis about sorbate is sort of weird.

So in order to "solve" the chemical part of the problem you have to assume ( ass out of u and me) that (1) sorbate is in all the sauces, (2) that sorbate is the only thing that the developer will reveal, and (3) the various sorbate species extracted, and/or sorbate interactions cause different Rf values in the sauces.

(1) isn't hard to believe for commercial sauces.

(2) is a really big leap since the sauces probably contain hundreds of chemicals.

(3) Isn't too hard to believe since even through potassium sorbate may be added to the hot sauce, it may be varioous sorbate species such as sorbic acid, or potassium sorbate, or sodium sorbate that might be extracted. Also the sorbate could be effected by pH changes in the development.

So all in all any "real" chemistry is ignored in this problem.

The last aspect is the logic problem within the chemical problem. The problem states that you ran 3 other sauces *besides* the "best" Sriracha. There are 6 samples on the plate, and you should have run the "best" Sriracha 2 times so that it is alongside each of the other three sauces.

Let's number the samples 1 to 6 from left to right. Sample 1 is a pure potassium sorbate reference. Both samples 2 and 5 must be the "best" Sriracha since these are the only Rf vales within 2-6 that line up, and the blob shapes are the same.

So:

- Sample 1 is next to 2. (Potassium sorbate reference)
- Sample 3 is next to 2. (i.e. 1st of 3 test sauces)
- Sample 4 is next to 5. (i.e. 2nd of 3 test sauces)
- Sample 6 is next to 5. (i.e. 3rd of 3 test sauces)

So Sample 3, test sauce "A", doesn't seem to have as much of the whatever makes Rf value of the Huy Fong Sriracha sorbate so high.

Sample 4, Test sauce "B", seems to be potassium sorbate.

Sample 5, Test sauce "C" seems to have something which inhibits sorbate traveling up the TLC plate.

Thus the whole problem has a decided slant towards a logic puzzle than a real chemistry problem.

Comment: I cleared the comment train here because some had been deleted already.  Let me know if you still need any of yours to incorporate into your answer.